# How to set DrRacket so that I can draw pictures

Tags: racket

I want to practice drawing pictures in DrRacket. I have read online:

first, I copy #lang slideshow in the definition area

then I click RUN

then It should be okay with pictures.

But my result is: after clicking RUN, I get: read-syntax: `#lang` not enabled
I don't know how to fix this. I use advanced student language.

Comment: The `slideshow` language is used for defining slideshows. While you *can* draw pictures in your slides, `slideshow` is not required for drawing. You also can't use it with the HtDP languages. The HtDP languages have "teachpacks" for drawing - look in the Language menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lower, left corner of DrRacket you will need to switch to
"Determine language from source".

The `slideshow` language is not a teaching language,
so that explains, why you can't run it with your
current language setting.

[image]

Comment: why "custom"? are there some more settings to change?

Comment: That's accidental. I must have changed something in the language menu, and now DrRacket says "custom" to tell me that I am not using default settings. I think, I changed a debug setting.

Comment: it's just that it makes the answer confusing, like that, without any explanation. :)

Comment: Agree. I attempted to take a screenshot of the lower, left corner - but that's not clear either.

Comment: Thanks, after I switch to determine language from source, it does work ：D